# How to override the JS getter & setter function using prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype, getter-setter

Need to know how to override the getters and setters by extending using prototypal inheritance

Following is an example to understand the issue

```
function A() {
    this._loading = "Welcome";
}

Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'loading', {
    get() {
        return this._loading+" from A";
    },
    set(value) {
        this._loading = value;
    }
});

function B() {}
Object.defineProperty(B.prototype, 'loading', {
    get() {
        return this._loading+" from B";
    },
    set(value) {
        this._loading = value;
    }
});

var a=new A();
var b=new B();

b.__proto__=a; // Not sure if this is wrong. This assigns the whole prototype of A to B so that B is submerged
```

My expected result is b.loading should return me 
**Welcome from B**

Instead its returning 
**Welcome from A**

Help is appreciated.

Comment: "*`b.__proto__=a;` Not sure if this is wrong.*" - yes, this is wrong. Drop it and you will get the expected output from `b.loading`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

In Javascript you have different way to handle "inheritance".
As you said, your implementation is not working because of the **proto** reassignation.

**1. Overriding prototype**
Usually [it is considered bad practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) to access prototype using `__proto__`. In your case you are re-assigning the whole prototype of B, so it will just replace all prototype.

```js
// Here you are overriding the prototype of "b"
b.__proto__=a;

// It refers to the prototype of a, so it the equivalent of calling a.loading
b.loading
```

**2. Inherits from other prototype - ES5**

```js
function B() {
  // Call the constructor of A giving the "B.this" context
  A.call(this)
}
// Inherits from prototype of A
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
Object.defineProperty(B.prototype, 'loading', {
    get() {
        return this._loading+" from B";
    }
});

// You won't need to instanciate A to inherits from it
const b = new B();
b.loading // "Welcome from B"
```

**3. A step further**
In a real world scenario you may want to inherits some properties from A, and override other properties in B. Because B inherits from A, you can call both methods from B.prototype and A.prototype.

```js
function A() {
  this._loading = "Welcome";
}

Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, "loadingA", {
    get: function loading() {
        return this._loading + " from A"
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, "loading", {
    get: function loading() {
        return this._loading + " from A"
    }
});


function B() {
  A.call(this)
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
Object.defineProperty(B.prototype, 'loading', {
    get() {
        return this._loading+" from B";
    }
});

var b = new B()
b.loading // Welcome from B
b.loadingA // Welcome from A
```

**4. A second step further - ES6+**
You may want to use ES6 class syntax sugar, it's less verbose and easier to understand ;)

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this._loading = "Welcome"
  }

  get loading() {
    return this._loading + " from A"
  }
}

class B extends A {
  get loading() {
    return this._loading + " from B"
  }
}

b.loading // Welcome from B
b.loadingA // Welcome from A
```

[Further readings on javascript inheritance](http://Further%20readings%20on%20javascript%20inheritance)